Closed time loop or not?
I've just finished re-reading The Light Of That Falls by James Islington, third in the Licanius trilogy. Spoilers for anyone who hasn't read it.
One of the premises of the time travel in the series appears to be that it follows the closed loop model with whatever has happened in the timeline of one person will happen for others when they reach that point (although not always in the way it appeared).
A second point is that the Augurs and Venerate with the ability to shape-shift are limited to imitating someone they have an imprint for, requiring them to have (personally) killed the 'model'. The only exception to this is when Davian is able to create a Vessel to reproduce the ability, and this only happens the once.
Throughout much of the story, it is known that a younger Tal'kamar will kill Davian. At the end it is revealed that

 the person killed is actually an older Tal'kamar/Caeden, who adopts Davian's appearance to fulfil the known fate and spare the real Davian. However, as Tal'kamar has never killed the actual Davian, he shouldn't have the imprint and wouldn't be able to shift into his appearance.

Is this a single example of a non-closed time loop (defeating destiny) or have I missed another explanation?

Don't forget that seemingly non-closed paradoxes can exist within a loop. The nature of a temporal loop is that the internal timeline within a loop doesn't need to be consistent.

When I was initially reading the book, I thought what you described is what was going to happen, and it does create a paradox.
I believe the book explains that to shapeshift to someone else, you need to have extinguished their source (which generally results in death), so logically, Caeden killing himself shapeshifted into Davian shouldnt have allowed him to shapeshift to Davian.  You might be able to make this logic work if we allow that they can actually take on any physical form that the person whose source they've taken can take, but I dont recall anyone else being able to shapeshift into a form that they didn't personally kill first.
Thankfully, the book actually avoids this completely.  Even bigger TLOATF spoilers:

This is where the epilogue scenes work to clear up what happened, and it connects a lot of points.  We learn that Davian is the child of Niha and Relith.  Caeden reveals to Niha that in order for the shapeshifting into Dar'gaithin to work, he had to extinguish the source of her unborn child, which she didnt even know existed.  So Caeden did what he needed to shapeshift into Davian before Davian was even born, he is the reason Davian has no source.


It also explains why Davian showed up late and could access Kan in Zvaelar.


Excellent, thank you. Was reading 'killed' in far too literal a sense which didn't work in this context.
